# Don't keep aspect ratio with jQuery resizable while holding shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm resizing a div with jQuery resizable and I only want to resize its height.

I managed to only resize while dragging bottom helper :

```
$('div').resizable({
   handles: 's',
});
```

But if I hold shift key, width is changing. 
See http://jsfiddle.net/6p20qjmr/3/

How can I disable this behavior?

**Edit:** The div container width may change after initial resizable call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a way to achieve what I want using `resize` parameter and reseting width after every resize event:

```
$(".resize").resizable({
    handles: 's',
    resize: function() {
        $(this).css('width', '');
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6p20qjmr/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, with this solution You can only enlarge element, but not shrink it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var $elt = $(".resize");
    var width = $elt.width();
   $elt.resizable({
       handles: 's',
       maxWidth: width,
       minWidth: width
    });
});
```

This may not be the best solution, but I am not super familiar with JQuery UI's resizable functionality. I'm not even sure why holding shift changes the functionality. If you could explain that, I may be able to provide a better solution that seems less hacky.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6p20qjmr/

Comment: That could be a solution but my div's width may change...

 -- There's a line is jQuery UI which enable ratio keeping: ``if (this._aspectRatio || b.shiftKey)``

Comment: @Tyrius I am not sure I understand. By specifying 's' as the only option, doesn't that mean you should only be able to make the element higher?

Comment: `Shift` key enables the `aspectRatio:true`; However, even if i use `aspectRatio:false` aspect `Shift` key overrides it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy s enable south helper, which allow to make height higher/lower.

Comment: @Tyrius So what is the problem with my solution? You are saying you may want to change the width of the element via JavaScript later? Because your original question indicates that you do not want the width of the element to change.

Comment: The DOM may change and change the container's width. See http://jsfiddle.net/6p20qjmr/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff That's not really clean, but it works. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Tyrius If you change the width via JavaScript, then it is going to change. What does that have to do with your original question. You want the aspect ratio to remain even if you change the width via JavaScript? Because if so, that has nothing to do with the resizable plugin.

Comment: Container width may change. I updated my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6p20qjmr/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $el = $('.resize').resizable({});
var resizable = $el.data('ui-resizable');
var old_mouse_drag = resizable._mouseDrag;

resizable._mouseDrag = function(e) {
  e.shiftKey = false;
  return old_mouse_drag.call(this, e);
};
```

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/e1wagrh9/